# OpenGL, interleaved VBO (vertex, normal and color) with light

Tags: opengl, colors, jogl, vbo, lighting

I have an interleaved VBO containing vertexes, normals and colors. Everything works as espected.

I want to have lights as well, but if I enable it, then colors are not working any more.

I guess this is because lights dont work with gl.glColor, but with color materials (as also  [here](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/lights.htm) specified, first question)

So, taking in account that I need to render no more than 10000 triangles and I need to switch color 3 times during the rendering, which is the best strategy that fits my needs?

Ps: I am also rendering several millions of triangles with other VBOs (but with just a color per VBO), so I guess gl.glBegin does not represent a valid option for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your hardware doesn't support shaders, you can use glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE) and glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL).

Comment: I tried, it seems to work, although colors appear very dark, especially white. What about shaders? How could I do with them? (Do you have a good link?)

Comment: http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/glsl_an_introduction/25007/ something like that. Shader is just a program for GPU, in it you can calculate result colors anyway you want. However, in your situation, i guess light is calculated just ok, and your color defects is a result of wrong light source setup. Check your light properties again. Also, you may want to add some ambient light to make everything brighter - i think it should work by calling glMaterialf for GL_AMBIENT_COLOR